# Correct way of populating object with waterfall

Tags: node.js

I have a following object in my node,js module, named data:

```
{
    "item_uuid": "77306c44-4175-4aee-866d-d8df89fa3ii9",
    "accounts": [{
        "accountid": "B15501",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "accountid": "S20000",
        "quantity": 1
    }]
}
```

I need to populate each account in accounts with a country code by passing accountid to an API, before passing the entire data for further processing.

So I loop each account in accounts and do the following:

```
data.accounts.forEach(function(account) {

    var clientAPI = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/" + account.accountid + "/?fields=country";
    request.get(clientAPI, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Unable to get country code for " +
                    account.accountid + " : " + err.message);
        } else {
            var clientData = JSON.parse(body);
            account.country_code = clientData.country
        }
    })
}

// once all accounts have got country code, perform insertion into database
processData(data);
```

Unfortunately the call to the clientAPI is async and it does not wait for the result to be returned hence when data reaches processData, it's still without country_code.

So I am trying waterfall here:

```
var waterfall = require('async-waterfall');

waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        data.accounts.forEach(function(account) {

            var clientAPI = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/" + account.accountid + "/?fields=country";
            request.get(clientAPI, function (err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Unable to get country code for " + account.accountid + " : " + err.message);
                } else {
                    var clientData = JSON.parse(body);
                    account.country_code = clientData.country
                }
            })
        }

        callback(null, data);
    }
], function(err, data){
    processData(data);          
})
```

Too bad, it still does not work, when it comes to processData(data), it still has no country_code.

What is that I am missing in using waterfall here? What else I can do alternatively to populate country_code above before processData(data)?

I must call the API to get the country_code for each account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try promises (and maybe the new await/async syntax in node 7.6+), they result in a more legible, logical flow of code.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'))

function getData(data){
  return Promise.each(data.accounts, function(account){
    const clientAPI = {
      method: 'GET',
      json: true,
      uri: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/${account.accountid}/?fields=country`,
    }
    return request.getAsync(clientAPI).then(function(response){
      if (!response.body.country) throw new Error('No country on '+account.accountid')
      account.country_code = response.body.country
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.error('Unable to get country code for '+account.accountid+' : '+err.message, err);
    })
  })
}

getData(data).then(function(){ processData(data) })
```

You can also use [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with some concurrency rather than [`Promise.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) which is serial and will wait for each request to complete before moving onto the next.

Not catching the error (or rethrowing `err`) will result in the Promise being rejected rather than just logged, which may be more useful for the program. The good thing about Promises is errors will bubble up, so you can handle errors in a more global manner at the beginning of your program/calls.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I am stuck with older node.js v4, how can I use promise without await/async syntax but just promise above?

Comment: Updated to straight promises. Basically anywhere there's an `await`  it becomes `.then()`

Comment: awesome, return Promise.each has save my day!

Answer (score 0):

This would be better achieved if you were using promises, or async/await, or generator syntax.

With callbacks, use a counter variable to keep track of how many requests you're sending and wait for the counter to reach a certain value before calling `processData`.

```
let counter = 0;

data.accounts.forEach(function(account) {

var clientAPI = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/" + account.accountid + "/?fields=country";
request.get(clientAPI, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to get country code for " +
                account.accountid + " : " + err.message);
        counter++
    } else {
        var clientData = JSON.parse(body);
        account.country_code = clientData.country
        counter++
    }
})
}

// once all accounts have got country code, perform insertion into database
if (counter === data.accounts.length) processData(data);
```

Comment: don't see how if (counter === data.accounts.length) would work here?